# Is there a substitute for poke face option in Blender 2.65?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have been trying to make a dice watching a YouTube video and in that they are using Blender 2.81a. However, I cant afford it as my computer doesn't have the required graphic card and processor (can't buy a new one for this because I am not a professional, just a beginner). So I have been using 2.65 as it is the one which works best in my computer. When I was making this cube, there was a need to make a poke face. But I cant find that option or any other any option to do it. Please help...

Comment: AFAIK version 2.79 should run on same hardware as 2.65 and has the poke faces operator.

Comment: Is Blender 2.8 really more resource hungry than 2.79 or 2.65? I'm occasionally running it an an old Thinkpad with Intel integrated graphics and I would even say it got a little more snappy with 2.8.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks @batFINGER your idea worked I was able to use 2.76b ( not 2.79 because they asked for more graphic card and something I didnt undersood ) But I got the poke face so Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If @batFINGER's suggestion doesn't work for you for some reason, then, with Pivot set to '**Individual Origins**', in Face mode you can <kbd>I</kbd> inset all your faces a little way (or by no distance) :

[image]

.. With 'Individual' checked. (This illustration has to be in a later version, but your adjustment should be available in the <kbd>T</kbd> toolbar region.)

Then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> you should be able to scale all faces to 0, followed by the old <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>B</kbd> .. or <kbd>W</kbd> menu .. 'Remove Doubles'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you  before I downloaded the 2.76 I tried your method and it worked as it was needed even though I had to do all individually but I was able to do it so Thanks